# EJB lookup - Failed to create remoting connection

Tags: jakarta-ee, lookup, ejb-3.1

i have a problem with lookup my ejb. In servlet all works fine, but i need to connect to ejb from remote klient.

from deployments console log:

```
 java:global/easymenu-webappEAR/EasyMenu/CounterBean!sk.jbase.projects.easymenu.CounterBeanRemote
 java:app/EasyMenu/CounterBean!sk.jbase.projects.easymenu.CounterBeanRemote
 java:module/CounterBean!sk.jbase.projects.easymenu.CounterBeanRemote
 java:jboss/exported/easymenu-webappEAR/EasyMenu/CounterBean!sk.jbase.projects.easymenu.CounterBeanRemote
 java:global/easymenu-webappEAR/EasyMenu/CounterBean
 java:app/EasyMenu/CounterBean
 java:module/CounterBean
```

i have ejbmodule in webapp (i dont know how separate it)

geting context:

```
public static InitialContext getInitialContext(String url) throws NamingException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
            "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    properties.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "pch");
    properties.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "peterch");

    return new InitialContext(properties);
}
```

lookup:

```
            CounterBeanRemote cbr = (CounterBeanRemote) ServiceLocator
                    .getInitialContext("remote://localhost:8080").lookup("java:app/EasyMenu/CounterBean!"
        + CounterBeanRemote.class.getName());

            System.out.println("Result: " + cbr.getMessage());
```

EXCEPTION

```
mar 20, 2013 10:27:04 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
mar 20, 2013 10:27:04 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
mar 20, 2013 10:27:04 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:36)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:121)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at sk.jbase.projects.easymenu.client.EasyMenuClient.getInitialContext(EasyMenuClient.java:58)
    at sk.jbase.projects.easymenu.client.EasyMenuClient.main(EasyMenuClient.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:89)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.NamingStoreCache.getRemoteNamingStore(NamingStoreCache.java:56)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateCachedNamingStore(InitialContextFactory.java:166)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateNamingStore(InitialContextFactory.java:139)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:104)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: I have exactly the same one....

Answer (score 0):

Which JBoss version do you use? 
In JBoss 7.1 the default remote port is 4447 and you should use the URL that follows after java:jboss/exported/. If you use "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming" then you need an "ejb:" prefix for the URL and the properties that are usually in the file jboss-ejb-client.properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the last nightly build of JBOSS AS 7.2. When I just reverted the jboss-client.jar in my classpath, to an older version, it started working like a charm.

Once you fix the URL and lookup above and the jboss-client.jar, that should do it.